# Android unexplained LogCat errors

Tags: java, android, exception, logcat

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error in logcat:

```
02-14 15:44:42.470: E/ActivityThread(32164): >>> handling: 109
```

It seems to occur when I open/close a new activity, though everything in the app seems fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why bother if your application is running normally? Probably this error is not connected with your application, it's just an another's app fault.

Comment: Does the app crash or display irregular behaviour when this happens? Is there any more of a logcat message, or is this the only line?

Comment: The 'Application' and 'PID' are from my app. I'm thorough and if this is adversely affecting the speed of my app, I want to quash it.

Comment: This is the only line, I directly copied and pasted it. My app behaves normally.

Comment: The error isn't being replicated on my other device, could it be a phone specific thing?

Comment: @Todd Davies probably. Different devices have different apps, Android versions, firmware, etc. Any of which could be outputting a message every time an activity starts. Does this message appear when you navigate other apps on the same device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the same app on another device and don't get these errors, so I am assuming that the error is related to the hardware, not my software.

If anybody else is developing on a ZTE Crescent/Orange San Francisco II, do you get these errors too?